# Compare 2 Tables and write RowID from Table A to Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have Table A with RowID, Date, Vendor and Cost, Confirmed
I have table B with RowID, Date, Vendor and Cost, Confirmed

Table A list our purchases.
 
Table B list the statement data from the credit card.

I would like to compare Date, Vendor and Cost in Table A with the same columns in Table B.  If there is a match with those three columns, then I would like to take the RowID value from Table A and write it to the matching row in Table B under the Confirmation column.

I am very new to SQL and I am not even sure this is a reasonable expectation.

What do you think?

Is this enough detail to provide your opinion?

Thank you for any help you can give.

Currently I am using an Outer Right Join to get all the rows that do NOT have a match.  What I really need is the opposite.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Perhaps you can give an example of what you already tried and what result you are getting? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It might help to know what database engine you are using...

My answers are going to relate to MS SQL Server, but much SQL Syntax is the same...

To answer your first question, I would write something like:

```
Update TableB Set Confirmation = TableA.RowID From TableA
Where TableA.Vendor = TableB.Vendor
And TableA.Cost = TableB.Cost
And TableA.Date = TableB.Date
```

I would use aliases, but I left them out to hopefully make it easier to understand.

To answer your second question, you can specify an INNER JOIN which is the opposite of an OUTER JOIN and as you mentioned, what you are looking for, as it will return ALL rows that Match and exclude the rest.

Comment: I really tried to be specific and I forgot the important part.  We are using MS SQL 2012.

Comment: Wow!  That seems so simple and makes sense.  I will try that shortly and let you know what the results were.  Thanks!!

Comment: japennell, I edited my answer to reflect that you should be setting the Confirmation column = TableA.RowID, my original code was setting the TableB.RowID = TableA.RowID.                       Aside from that the code below from Krone does the same thing but I am using an implicit join and Krone is explicitly joining the two tables. SQL handles both with the same logic but it's good practice to be specific as a beginner and not take shortcuts as I have done.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with this query

```
UPDATE 
    B
SET 
    Confirmation = A.RowID
FROM
    TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
    ON B.Vendor = A.Vendor
    AND B.Cost = A.Cost
    AND B.Date = A.Date
```

Basically we do an inner join to keep the intersection (the records that match) of the two tables. and update the records that coincided from table B with the id of table A